python 3.10 and error when install tensorflow_federated

python version: 3.10
pip version: 24.0

I use env.
TFF required: Python <3.12, >=3.9
when I pip install tensorflow_federated in terminal (env is on) and received this problem:
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\UDA_LEARNING\UDA_DO AN TRI TUE NHAN TAO & UNG DUNG\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "E:\UDA_LEARNING\UDA_DO AN TRI TUE NHAN TAO & UNG DUNG\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "E:\UDA_LEARNING\UDA_DO AN TRI TUE NHAN TAO & UNG DUNG\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\JOS UC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51vn4i37\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\JOS UC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51vn4i37\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\JOS UC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51vn4i37\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup   
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\JOS UC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51vn4i37\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup   
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

How do I fix it?
run: pip install tensorflow_federated in terminal and noticed:

RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.

my python version: 3.10.
what should I do?
